# C# MD5 Hash of String and already MD5 hashed String

Tags: c#, md5, concatenation

Is it possible to create a MD5 Hash of a String and an already MD5 hashed String?

Example:

MD5 of 'test1234' is '16d7a4fca7442dda3ad93c9a726597e4'

Is this possible:
md5('Hello,test1234') = md5('Hello,' + 16d7a4fca7442dda3ad93c9a726597e4)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you are asking "Is it always true that `md5(a + b) == md5(a + md5(b))`?", then the answer is: no.

Comment: Yes, I know. Other question: What should I do, that the same hash comes out?

Comment: Could you please clarify the question and use-case?

Comment: user3260533 - that second question is not in this post. You should add the question to this post, or ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

If you had tried this, you would know that the answer is **yes, it is**, as long as you properly concatenate the MD5('test1234') resulting string properly to 'Hello'. But the MD5 hashes will (pretty much) always be different.